# How to undo an edit of a QListWidgetItem in PySide/PyQt?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyside, qlistwidget

**Short version**

How do you implement undo functionality for edits made on `QListWidgetItems` in PySide/PyQt?

**Hint from a Qt tutorial?**

The following tutorial written for Qt users (c++) likely has the answer, but I am not a c++ person, so get a bit lost: [Using Undo/Redo with Item Views](http://www.qtcentre.org/wiki/index.php?title=Using_Undo/Redo_with_Item_Views)

**Longer version**

I am using a `QListWidget` to learn my way around PyQt's [Undo Framework](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qundo.html) (with the help of [an article](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1187104) on the topic). I am fine with undo/redo when I implement a command myself (like deleting an item from the list).

I also want to make the `QListWidgetItems` in the widget editable. This is easy enough: just add the `ItemIsEditable` flag to each item. The problem is, *how can I push such edits onto the undo stack*, so I can then undo/redo them?

Below is a simple working example that shows a list, lets you delete items,and undo/redo such deletions. The application displays both the list and the the undo stack. What needs to be done to get edits onto that stack?

**Simple working example**

```
from PySide import QtGui, QtCore

class TodoList(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_DeleteOnClose)
        self.initUI()
        self.show()

    def initUI(self):
        self.todoList = self.makeTodoList()
        self.undoStack = QtGui.QUndoStack(self)
        undoView = QtGui.QUndoView(self.undoStack)
        buttonLayout = self.buttonSetup()
        mainLayout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout(self)
        mainLayout.addWidget(undoView)
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.todoList)
        mainLayout.addLayout(buttonLayout)
        self.setLayout(mainLayout)
        self.makeConnections()

    def buttonSetup(self):
        #Make buttons 
        self.deleteButton = QtGui.QPushButton("Delete")
        self.undoButton = QtGui.QPushButton("Undo")
        self.redoButton = QtGui.QPushButton("Redo")
        self.quitButton = QtGui.QPushButton("Quit")
        #Lay them out
        buttonLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        buttonLayout.addWidget(self.deleteButton)
        buttonLayout.addStretch()
        buttonLayout.addWidget(self.undoButton)
        buttonLayout.addWidget(self.redoButton)
        buttonLayout.addStretch()
        buttonLayout.addWidget(self.quitButton)
        return buttonLayout

    def makeConnections(self):
        self.deleteButton.clicked.connect(self.deleteItem)
        self.quitButton.clicked.connect(self.close)
        self.undoButton.clicked.connect(self.undoStack.undo)
        self.redoButton.clicked.connect(self.undoStack.redo)

    def deleteItem(self):
        rowSelected=self.todoList.currentRow()
        rowItem = self.todoList.item(rowSelected)
        if rowItem is None:
            return
        command = CommandDelete(self.todoList, rowItem, rowSelected,
                                "Delete item '{0}'".format(rowItem.text()))
        self.undoStack.push(command)

    def makeTodoList(self):
        todoList = QtGui.QListWidget()
        allTasks = ('Fix door', 'Make dinner', 'Read', 
                    'Program in PySide', 'Be nice to everyone')
        for task in allTasks:
            todoItem=QtGui.QListWidgetItem(task)
            todoList.addItem(todoItem)
            todoItem.setFlags(QtCore.Qt.ItemIsSelectable | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled)
        return todoList


class CommandDelete(QtGui.QUndoCommand):
    def __init__(self, listWidget, item, row, description):
        super(CommandDelete, self).__init__(description)
        self.listWidget = listWidget
        self.string = item.text()
        self.row = row

    def redo(self):
        self.listWidget.takeItem(self.row)

    def undo(self):
        addItem = QtGui.QListWidgetItem(self.string)
        addItem.setFlags(QtCore.Qt.ItemIsSelectable | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled)
        self.listWidget.insertItem(self.row, addItem)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    myList=TodoList()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Note I posted an e[arlier version of this question](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/61881-Undo-edit-of-QListWidgetItem) at QtCentre.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That tutorial you mentioned is really not very helpful. There are indeed many approaches to undo-redo implementation for views, we just need to choose the simplest one. If you deal with small lists, the simpliest way is to save all data on each change and restore full list from scratch on each undo or redo operation.

If you still want atomic changes list, you can track user-made edits with `QListWidget::itemChanged` signal. There are two problems with that:

- Any other item change in the list will also trigger this signal, so you need to wrap any code that changes items into `QObject::blockSignals` calls to block unwanted signals.
- There is no way to get previous text, you can only get new text. The solution is either save all list data to variable, use and update it on change or save the edited item's text before it's edited. QListWidget is pretty reticent about its internal editor state, so I decided to use `QListWidget::currentItemChanged` assuming that user won't find a way to edit an item without making is current first.

So this is the changes that will make it work (besides adding `ItemIsEditable` flag in two places):

```
def __init__(self):
    #...
    self.todoList.itemChanged.connect(self.itemChanged)
    self.todoList.currentItemChanged.connect(self.currentItemChanged)
    self.textBeforeEdit = ""

def itemChanged(self, item):
    command = CommandEdit(self.todoList, item, self.todoList.row(item),
        self.textBeforeEdit, 
        "Rename item '{0}' to '{1}'".format(self.textBeforeEdit, item.text()))
    self.undoStack.push(command)

def currentItemChanged(self, item):
    self.textBeforeEdit = item.text()
```

And the new change class:

```
class CommandEdit(QtGui.QUndoCommand):
    def __init__(self, listWidget, item, row, textBeforeEdit, description):
        super(CommandEdit, self).__init__(description)
        self.listWidget = listWidget
        self.textBeforeEdit = textBeforeEdit
        self.textAfterEdit = item.text()
        self.row = row

    def redo(self):
        self.listWidget.blockSignals(True)
        self.listWidget.item(self.row).setText(self.textAfterEdit)
        self.listWidget.blockSignals(False)

    def undo(self):
        self.listWidget.blockSignals(True)
        self.listWidget.item(self.row).setText(self.textBeforeEdit)
        self.listWidget.blockSignals(False)
```

Comment: What an instructive answer! We could even use the `currentTextChanged` instead of `currentItemChanged`, but frankly I prefer the former (what you used) as it is more scalable for things like checkbox states. One question: the `currentItemChanged` documentation says it emits both the `current` item and `previous` item. But it seems it just sends the newly selected (current) item to its slot, even though at the Qt docs it says `void QListWidget.currentItemChanged(currentItem, previousItem)` (http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8-snapshot/qlistwidget.html#currentItemChanged).

Comment: Qt allows slots to have fewer arguments than signals. If you add second argument to the slot you will get `previous` item. It's not useful here though.

Comment: Strangely, I tried that and second parameter is just read as type `None`.  Luckily it doesn't matter for this one, but the behavior (in PySide anyway) seems at odds with docs. Maybe a separate question, or maybe a question for a specialized Qt forum?

Comment: I figured out the problem: one my very first click, the previous item was (correctly) returned as `None`! Silly mistake. Once I click on another item, we have a current and previous item as expected from the signal.

Answer (score 1):

I would do it like this:

Create a custom [`QItemDelegate`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qabstractitemdelegate.html#editorEvent) and use these two signals:

- `editorEvent`
- `closeEditor`

On `editorEvent`: Save current state

On `closeEditor`: Get new state and create a `QUndoCommand` that set the new state for `Redo` and the old state for `Undo`.

Comment: your hint holds promise, though editorEvent may not be the most efficient time to save something as it is called so often (even with a single mouse click it is called multiple times). Perhaps it would be more efficient, and simpler, to somehow incorporate your stratety via createEditor() and setModelData(), which are only called once with each edit?

Comment: editorEvent is called when editing starts and on MouseMove. You could ignore the mouse Events and just use the editing start event.

Answer (score 0):

Each time you verify and accept the new text of the item, save it as list item data. Quasi-semi-pseudo-code:

```
OnItemEdited(Item* item)
{
    int dataRole{ 32 }; //or greater (see ItemDataRole documentation)

    if (Validate(item->text()) {

        item->setData(dataRole, item->text());

    } else { //Restore previous value

        item->setText(item->data(dataRole).toString());
    }
}
```

I'm sorry if it looks too much like C++.