# How to treat click events differently for an item's checkbox versus its text? (PyQt/PySide/Qt)

Tags: pyqt, pyside, signals-slots, undo-redo, qstandarditemmodel

I have a `QStandardItemModel` in which each item is checkable. I want different slots to be called when I click on the item's checkbox, on one hand, versus when I click on its text, on the other. My ultimate goal is to have text edits, and changes in checkbox state, go onto the `QUndoStack` separately.

In my reimplementation of `clicked` I want to treat checkbox clicks and text clicks differently. So far, I have found no way to differentiate these events in [the documentation](http://srinikom.github.io/pyside-docs/PySide/QtGui/QCheckBox.html) for `QCheckBox` or `QStandardItem.` While `QCheckBox` has a `toggled` signal that I can use, I am not sure how to specifically listen for clicks on the text area.

I am trying to avoid having to set up coordinates manually and then listen for clicks in the different regions of the view of the item.

It doesn't seem this will be as simple as calling something like `itemChanged`, because that only gives you the *new* state of the item, not the previous state. Based on previous questions, I believe you need some way to pack the previous state into the undo stack, so you know what to revert to. That's what I am aiming to do with `clicked`, but there might be a better way.

This question piggybacks on the previous two in this series, in which I'm trying to figure out how to undo things in models:

- [How to undo edit of QStandardItem in PySide/PyQt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29527610/how-to-undo-edit-of-qstandarditem-in-pyside-pyqt)
- [How to undo an edit of a QListWidgetItem in PySide/PyQt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28954565/how-to-undo-an-edit-of-a-qlistwidgetitem-in-pyside-pyqt)

Comment: It is a hassle, but you can create a QCheckBox and embed the widget inside of a QTreeWidget (setItemWidget). You can connect one method to the QCheckBox clicked method and connect another method to the itemChanged signal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on [ekhumoro's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29659545/1886357) and code nuggets, I built a treeview of a `QStandardItemModel` that emits a custom signal when an item changes. The code differentiates the text versus the checkbox changing via the role in `setData` (for text, use `Qt.EditRole` and for checkbox state changes use `Qt.CheckStateRole`) :

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from PySide import QtGui, QtCore
import sys

class CommandTextEdit(QtGui.QUndoCommand):
    def __init__(self, tree, item, oldText, newText, description):
        QtGui.QUndoCommand.__init__(self, description)
        self.item = item
        self.tree = tree
        self.oldText = oldText
        self.newText = newText

    def redo(self):      
        self.item.model().itemDataChanged.disconnect(self.tree.itemDataChangedSlot) 
        self.item.setText(self.newText)
        self.item.model().itemDataChanged.connect(self.tree.itemDataChangedSlot) 

    def undo(self):
        self.item.model().itemDataChanged.disconnect(self.tree.itemDataChangedSlot) 
        self.item.setText(self.oldText)
        self.item.model().itemDataChanged.connect(self.tree.itemDataChangedSlot) 


class CommandCheckStateChange(QtGui.QUndoCommand):
    def __init__(self, tree, item, oldCheckState, newCheckState, description):
        QtGui.QUndoCommand.__init__(self, description)
        self.item = item
        self.tree = tree
        self.oldCheckState = QtCore.Qt.Unchecked if oldCheckState == 0 else QtCore.Qt.Checked
        self.newCheckState = QtCore.Qt.Checked if oldCheckState == 0 else QtCore.Qt.Unchecked

    def redo(self): #disoconnect to avoid recursive loop b/w signal-slot
        self.item.model().itemDataChanged.disconnect(self.tree.itemDataChangedSlot) 
        self.item.setCheckState(self.newCheckState)
        self.item.model().itemDataChanged.connect(self.tree.itemDataChangedSlot) 

    def undo(self):
        self.item.model().itemDataChanged.disconnect(self.tree.itemDataChangedSlot)
        self.item.setCheckState(self.oldCheckState)
        self.item.model().itemDataChanged.connect(self.tree.itemDataChangedSlot) 


class StandardItemModel(QtGui.QStandardItemModel):
    itemDataChanged = QtCore.Signal(object, object, object, object)


class StandardItem(QtGui.QStandardItem):
    def setData(self, newValue, role=QtCore.Qt.UserRole + 1):
        if role == QtCore.Qt.EditRole:
            oldValue = self.data(role)
            QtGui.QStandardItem.setData(self, newValue, role)
            model = self.model()
            #only emit signal if newvalue is different from old
            if model is not None and oldValue != newValue:
                model.itemDataChanged.emit(self, oldValue, newValue, role)
            return True
        if role == QtCore.Qt.CheckStateRole:
            oldValue = self.data(role)
            QtGui.QStandardItem.setData(self, newValue, role)
            model = self.model()
            if model is not None and oldValue != newValue:
                model.itemDataChanged.emit(self, oldValue, newValue, role)
            return True
        QtGui.QStandardItem.setData(self, newValue, role)


class UndoableTree(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent = None)
        self.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_DeleteOnClose)
        self.view = QtGui.QTreeView()
        self.model = self.createModel()
        self.view.setModel(self.model)
        self.view.expandAll()
        self.undoStack = QtGui.QUndoStack(self)
        undoView = QtGui.QUndoView(self.undoStack)
        buttonLayout = self.buttonSetup()
        mainLayout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout(self)
        mainLayout.addWidget(undoView)
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.view)
        mainLayout.addLayout(buttonLayout)
        self.setLayout(mainLayout)
        self.makeConnections()

    def makeConnections(self):
        self.model.itemDataChanged.connect(self.itemDataChangedSlot)
        self.quitButton.clicked.connect(self.close)
        self.undoButton.clicked.connect(self.undoStack.undo)
        self.redoButton.clicked.connect(self.undoStack.redo)

    def itemDataChangedSlot(self, item, oldValue, newValue, role):
        if role == QtCore.Qt.EditRole:
            command = CommandTextEdit(self, item, oldValue, newValue,
                "Text changed from '{0}' to '{1}'".format(oldValue, newValue))
            self.undoStack.push(command)
            return True
        if role == QtCore.Qt.CheckStateRole:
            command = CommandCheckStateChange(self, item, oldValue, newValue, 
                "CheckState changed from '{0}' to '{1}'".format(oldValue, newValue))
            self.undoStack.push(command)
            return True

    def buttonSetup(self):
        self.undoButton = QtGui.QPushButton("Undo")
        self.redoButton = QtGui.QPushButton("Redo")
        self.quitButton = QtGui.QPushButton("Quit")
        buttonLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        buttonLayout.addStretch()
        buttonLayout.addWidget(self.undoButton)
        buttonLayout.addWidget(self.redoButton)
        buttonLayout.addStretch()
        buttonLayout.addWidget(self.quitButton)
        return buttonLayout

    def createModel(self):
        model = StandardItemModel()
        model.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(['Titles', 'Summaries'])
        rootItem = model.invisibleRootItem()
        item0 = [StandardItem('Title0'), StandardItem('Summary0')]
        item00 = [StandardItem('Title00'), StandardItem('Summary00')]
        item01 = [StandardItem('Title01'), StandardItem('Summary01')]
        item0[0].setCheckable(True)
        item00[0].setCheckable(True)
        item01[0].setCheckable(True)
        rootItem.appendRow(item0)
        item0[0].appendRow(item00)
        item0[0].appendRow(item01)
        return model


def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    newTree = UndoableTree()
    newTree.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())    

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 2):

The `clicked` signal seems to be entirely the wrong way to track changes. How are you going to deal with changes made via the keyboard? And what about changes that are made programmatically? For an undo stack to work correctly, every change has to be recorded, and in exactly the same order that it was made.

If you're using a `QStandardItemModel`, the [`itemChanged`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qstandarditemmodel.html#itemChanged) signal is almost exactly what you want. The main problem with it, though, is that although it sends the *item* that changed, it gives you no information about *what* changed. So it looks like you would need to do some subclassing and emit a custom signal that does that:

```
class StandardItemModel(QtGui.QStandardItemModel):
    itemDataChanged = QtCore.Signal(object, object, object)

class StandardItem(QtGui.QStandardItem):
    def setData(self, newValue, role=QtCore.Qt.UserRole + 1):
        oldValue = self.data(role)
        QtGui.QStandardItem.setData(self, newValue, role)
        model = self.model()
        if model is not None:
            model.itemDataChanged.emit(oldValue, newvValue, role)
```

Note that the signal will only be emitted for changes made *after* the item has been added to the model.

Comment: excellent critique, I wish you had stepped in here to set me straight :):  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29527610/how-to-undo-edit-of-qstandarditem-in-pyside-pyqt?lq=1. Will look at this when done with work tonight....and try to see if I can use your idea in that previous post about pushing text edits onto the undostack....

Comment: I think your solution doesn't work: if just getting the data was enough, `itemChanged` would have been fine (for the text editing case). But it only returns the *new* text, not the old text. Hence, the tricks that have been employed in the two previous questions in this series (that I have now linked to explicitly in my question).

Comment: Maybe the thing to do is a conditional: first check to see if the checkstate has changed, and if it has *not*, then update the text. Even then I need a way to store the previous text that was there, and I am open to signals other than 'clicked' which I admit was probably not the best. Perhaps just the selected item instead of clicked item.

Comment: @neuronet. I don't see the problem. The example code in my answer was just a quick sketch - it can easily be adapted to do whatever you want (I have tweaked it a little to show what I mean). The important point to realise is that `data()` and `setData()` are the single points of exit and entry for *all* data changes made to a standard model item. All other APIs utlimately depend on them: it's a basic feature of [Model Subclassing](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/model-view-programming.html#model-subclassing-reference).

Comment: Ah thanks for adding how to get the previous value, it is instructive in ways more than just with this question, but has helped me understand better the logic of data/setData. Will wrestle with this after work today.

Comment: I have finally finished a simple little example using many of your suggestions....http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/88065/to-do-tree-application-with-undo-redo-functionality Just in case anyone wants to comment there....cough cough...

Comment: @eric I ported your example to mine PyQt QTreeView with checkboxes, but needed to remove the return True in class StandardItem(QtGui.QStandardItem): to prevent 'TypeError: invalid result from StandardItem.setData()' any idea about why ?