# Performing undo and redo operation on QTableWidget

Tags: qt, qtablewidget, qmodelindex

I am using `QTableWidget` to display a table to plot a graph. User can perform the operations: enter, copy, cut and paste, add row, add column, insert, delete etc. All these operation should be stacked so that user can undo or redo all the operations.

I looked into `QUndoStack`, but in the context of `QTableWidget` I am not sure what data or object I will have to push to the stack.

Comment: Do you have QUndoCommand already? Actually you will need to create a class that inherit from QUndoCommand.

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28954565/how-to-undo-an-edit-of-a-qlistwidgetitem-in-pyside-pyqt/29166218#29166218

Comment: Apin : no i used the concept of QundoCommand in QGraphicsItem in view. there im managing only adding and removing items. but here table data.

Answer (score 2):

As it for me you have to remember value before editing and after in a class inherited from`QUndoCommand`, so that `undo()` and `redo()` can restore state you want

Comment: but what for adding row, column , insert ? if i store only data.?

Comment: First of all you have to write down all opeartion you have to do and what is changing.

For example: 
Edit a cell, you have to remember row, column and 2 strings. Add row, then you have to remember where it was added. Remove row, row index and row data