# QDataWidgetMapper; mapping TableWidget to model

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5, qtablewidget, undo-redo, qdatawidgetmapper

I am not finding any documentation showing which widgets QDataWidgetMapper actually works for and have not found any implementation of mapping with a QTableWidget.

It definitely works for QLineEdit's and QComboBoxes, which are input widgets, but is it possible to map to a QTableWidget?

Goal is to use QUndoStack to undo/redo text change in each widget when added to the QUndostack. I want to be able to undo/redo text changes for the items in the QTableWidget as well as the QLineEdits and QComboBoxes.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import sys

class CommandTextEdit(QtWidgets.QUndoCommand):
    def __init__(self, window, index, oldText, newText, description):
        super(CommandTextEdit,self).__init__()
        self.index = index
        self.window = window
        self.oldText = oldText
        self.newText = newText

    def redo(self):
        self.index.model().itemDataChanged.disconnect(self.window.itemDataChangedSlot)
        self.index.model().setData(self.index, self.newText, QtCore.Qt.EditRole)
        self.index.model().itemDataChanged.connect(self.window.itemDataChangedSlot)

    def undo(self):
        self.index.model().itemDataChanged.disconnect(self.window.itemDataChangedSlot)
        self.index.model().setData(self.index, self.oldText, QtCore.Qt.EditRole)
        self.index.model().itemDataChanged.connect(self.window.itemDataChangedSlot)

class Model(QtCore.QAbstractListModel):
    itemDataChanged = QtCore.pyqtSignal(object,object, object, object)
    def __init__(self, text = [], parent = None):
        super(Model,self).__init__(parent)
        self._text = text

    def rowCount(self,parent=QtCore.QModelIndex()):
        return len(self._text)

    def data(self,index,role):
        row = index.row()
        if role == QtCore.Qt.EditRole:
            return self._text[row]

        if role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
            value = self._text[row]
            return self._text[row]

    def model(self):
        return self

    def flags(self, index):
        return QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEditable |QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsSelectable

    def setData(self, index, value, role = QtCore.Qt.UserRole + 1):
        if index.isValid():
           if role == QtCore.Qt.EditRole:
                oldValue = self.data(index,role)
                self._text[index.row()] = value
                self.dataChanged.emit(index, index)
                if oldValue != value:
                    self.itemDataChanged.emit(index, oldValue, value, role)
                return True
        return False

class Window(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super(Window,self).__init__(parent)
        self.setCentralWidget(QtWidgets.QWidget(self))
        self.setWindowTitle('Widget Mapping GUI')
        mainlayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        #Information for widgets
        items = ["","H","N","M"]
        #LineEdit1
        self.labelLineEdit1 = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        self.labelLineEdit1.setText('LineEdit1')
        self.LineEdit1 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        firstBox = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        firstBox.addWidget(self.labelLineEdit1)
        firstBox.addWidget(self.LineEdit1)
        #LineEdit2
        self.labelLineEdit2 = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        self.labelLineEdit2.setText('LineEdit2')
        self.LineEdit2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        secondBox = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        secondBox.addWidget(self.labelLineEdit2)
        secondBox.addWidget(self.LineEdit2)
        #ComboBox1
        self.labelComboBox1 = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        self.labelComboBox1.setText('ComboBox1')
        self.ComboBox1 = QtWidgets.QComboBox()
        self.ComboBox1.addItems(items)

        thirdBox = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        thirdBox.addWidget(self.labelComboBox1)
        thirdBox.addWidget(self.ComboBox1)
        #ComboBox2
        self.labelComboBox2 = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        self.labelComboBox2.setText('ComboBox2')
        self.ComboBox2 = QtWidgets.QComboBox()
        self.ComboBox2.addItems(items)

        fourthBox = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        fourthBox.addWidget(self.labelComboBox2)
        fourthBox.addWidget(self.ComboBox2)
        #TableWidget
        self.TableWidget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(5,1)
        #Set header labels
        self.TableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(["Dimensions"])
        self.TableWidget.setVerticalHeaderLabels(["A","B","C","D","E"])
        self.TableWidget.setItem(0,1,QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem('1'))

        fifthBox = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        fifthBox.addWidget(self.TableWidget)
        #Add Layouts
        mainlayout.addLayout(firstBox)
        mainlayout.addLayout(secondBox)
        mainlayout.addLayout(thirdBox)
        mainlayout.addLayout(fourthBox)
        mainlayout.addLayout(fifthBox)
        self.centralWidget().setLayout(mainlayout)
        #Model
        self.mapper = None
        self.model = Model(['','','','',''])
        self.setModel(self.model)
        #QUndoStack
        self.undoStack = QtWidgets.QUndoStack()
        self.stackView = QtWidgets.QUndoView(self.undoStack)
        self.stackView.setWindowTitle('StackView')
        self.stackView.show()
        #Run init methods
        self.createActions()
        self.makeConnections()
        self.listViewMethod()

    def createActions(self):
        self.UndoAct = QtWidgets.QAction("Undo", self)
        self.UndoAct.setShortcut(QtGui.QKeySequence.Undo)
        self.UndoAct.triggered.connect(self.undoStack.undo)
        self.RedoAct = QtWidgets.QAction("Redo", self)
        self.RedoAct.setShortcut(QtGui.QKeySequence.Redo)
        self.RedoAct.triggered.connect(self.undoStack.redo)
        self.toolbar = self.addToolBar('Exit')
        self.toolbar.addAction(self.UndoAct)
        self.toolbar.addAction(self.RedoAct)

    def listViewMethod(self):
        self.listView = QtWidgets.QListView()
        self.listView.setModel(self.model)
        self.listView.setWindowTitle('ListView')
        self.listView.show()

    def makeConnections(self):
        self.model.itemDataChanged.connect(self.itemDataChangedSlot)

    def setModel(self, model):
        self.mapper = QtWidgets.QDataWidgetMapper(self)
        self.mapper.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Vertical)
        self.mapper.setModel(self.model)
        self.mapper.addMapping(self.LineEdit1, 0)
        self.mapper.addMapping(self.LineEdit2, 1)
        self.mapper.addMapping(self.ComboBox1, 2)
        self.mapper.addMapping(self.ComboBox2, 3)
        self.mapper.addMapping(self.TableWidget,4)
        self.mapper.toFirst()

    def itemDataChangedSlot(self, index, oldValue, value, role):
        if role == QtCore.Qt.EditRole:
            command = CommandTextEdit(self, index, oldValue, value, "Text changed from '{0}' to '{1}'".format(oldValue, value))
            self.undoStack.push(command)

def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())



if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: A data-mapper is designed to map *one* field of a record to *one* display widget. But a table does not typically display a single value - so you'd have to map *each one of its cells* to a field of the record. If the table has a fixed number of cells, this might be feasible; if not, you will need to maintain a separate backing model for the table (along with a separate undo/redo command to update it). There's a [question here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28954565/984421) which deals with undo/redo for item-views.

Comment: @ekhumoro How do you map a cell to the record, because `addMapping()` expects a widget? I am able to use `setCellWidget(1,0,QtWidgets.QLineEdit())`, and then map to it using `cellWidget()`, is there another way of mapping the cells without making them `QLineEdits`?

Comment: Why do you need another way? A data-widget-mapper is designed to map widgets to data in a strictly one-to-one manner (see the notes to [addMapping](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdatawidgetmapper.html#addMapping)). So cell-widgets would appear to be the perfect way to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To map the items of a `QTableWidget`, I used the `setCellWidget` method to map each cell to the model using a custom QLineEdit class.

Updated Code:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import sys

#implemented stylesheets for QLineEdit to imitate a QTableWidgetItem 
class CustomLineEdit(QtWidgets.QLineEdit):
    def __init__(self):
        super(CustomLineEdit,self).__init__()
        self.setReadOnly(True)
        self.setFrame(False)
        self.setStyleSheet("QLineEdit { border: none; } \n" \
                           "QLineEdit::focus {background-color: #3daee9;} \n"\
                           "QLineEdit::focus::pressed {background-color: none;} \n"\
                           "QLineEdit::hover {background-color: #3daee9;}"
                            )
    def mouseDoubleClickEvent(self,event):
        self.setReadOnly(False)
        self.setStyleSheet("QLineEdit { border: none; \nbackground-color: none;} \n" \
                            )

    def focusOutEvent(self,event):
        self.setReadOnly(True)
        self.setStyleSheet("QLineEdit { border: none; } \n" \
                           "QLineEdit::focus {background-color: #3daee9;} \n"\
                           "QLineEdit::focus::pressed {background-color: none;} \n"\
                           "QLineEdit::hover {background-color: #3daee9;}"
                            )

class CommandTextEdit(QtWidgets.QUndoCommand):
    def __init__(self, window, index, oldText, newText, description):
        super(CommandTextEdit,self).__init__()
        self.index = index
        self.window = window
        self.oldText = oldText
        self.newText = newText

    def redo(self):
        self.index.model().itemDataChanged.disconnect(self.window.itemDataChangedSlot)
        self.index.model().setData(self.index, self.newText, QtCore.Qt.EditRole)
        self.index.model().itemDataChanged.connect(self.window.itemDataChangedSlot)

    def undo(self):
        self.index.model().itemDataChanged.disconnect(self.window.itemDataChangedSlot)
        self.index.model().setData(self.index, self.oldText, QtCore.Qt.EditRole)
        self.index.model().itemDataChanged.connect(self.window.itemDataChangedSlot)

class Model(QtCore.QAbstractListModel):
    itemDataChanged = QtCore.pyqtSignal(object,object, object, object)
    def __init__(self, text = [], parent = None):
        super(Model,self).__init__(parent)
        self._text = text

    def rowCount(self,parent=QtCore.QModelIndex()):
        return len(self._text)

    def data(self,index,role):
        row = index.row()
        if role == QtCore.Qt.EditRole:
            return self._text[row]

        if role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
            value = self._text[row]
            return self._text[row]

    def model(self):
        return self

    def flags(self, index):
        return QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEditable |QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsSelectable

    def setData(self, index, value, role = QtCore.Qt.UserRole + 1):
        if index.isValid():
           if role == QtCore.Qt.EditRole:
                oldValue = self.data(index,role)
                self._text[index.row()] = value
                self.dataChanged.emit(index, index)
                if oldValue != value:
                    self.itemDataChanged.emit(index, oldValue, value, role)
                return True
        return False

class Window(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super(Window,self).__init__(parent)
        self.setCentralWidget(QtWidgets.QWidget(self))
        self.setWindowTitle('Widget Mapping GUI')
        mainlayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        #Information for widgets
        items = ["","H","N","M"]
        #LineEdit1
        self.labelLineEdit1 = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        self.labelLineEdit1.setText('LineEdit1')
        self.LineEdit1 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        firstBox = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        firstBox.addWidget(self.labelLineEdit1)
        firstBox.addWidget(self.LineEdit1)
        #LineEdit2
        self.labelLineEdit2 = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        self.labelLineEdit2.setText('LineEdit2')
        self.LineEdit2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        secondBox = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        secondBox.addWidget(self.labelLineEdit2)
        secondBox.addWidget(self.LineEdit2)
        #ComboBox1
        self.labelComboBox1 = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        self.labelComboBox1.setText('ComboBox1')
        self.ComboBox1 = QtWidgets.QComboBox()
        self.ComboBox1.addItems(items)

        thirdBox = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        thirdBox.addWidget(self.labelComboBox1)
        thirdBox.addWidget(self.ComboBox1)
        #ComboBox2
        self.labelComboBox2 = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        self.labelComboBox2.setText('ComboBox2')
        self.ComboBox2 = QtWidgets.QComboBox()
        self.ComboBox2.addItems(items)

        fourthBox = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        fourthBox.addWidget(self.labelComboBox2)
        fourthBox.addWidget(self.ComboBox2)
        #TableWidget
        self.TableWidget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(5,1)
        #Set header labels
        self.TableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(["Dimensions"])
        self.TableWidget.setVerticalHeaderLabels(["A","B","C","D","E"])
        self.TableWidget.setCellWidget(0,0,CustomLineEdit())
        self.TableWidget.setCellWidget(1,0,CustomLineEdit())
        self.TableWidget.setCellWidget(2,0,CustomLineEdit())
        self.TableWidget.setCellWidget(3,0,CustomLineEdit())
        self.TableWidget.setCellWidget(4,0,CustomLineEdit())
        self.TableWidget.setItem(1,0,QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem('1'))
        fifthBox = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        fifthBox.addWidget(self.TableWidget)
        #Add Layouts
        mainlayout.addLayout(firstBox)
        mainlayout.addLayout(secondBox)
        mainlayout.addLayout(thirdBox)
        mainlayout.addLayout(fourthBox)
        mainlayout.addLayout(fifthBox)
        self.centralWidget().setLayout(mainlayout)
        #Model
        self.mapper = None
        self.model = Model(['' for i in range(9)])
        self.setModel(self.model)
        #QUndoStack
        self.undoStack = QtWidgets.QUndoStack()
        self.stackView = QtWidgets.QUndoView(self.undoStack)
        self.stackView.setWindowTitle('StackView')
        self.stackView.show()
        #Run init methods
        self.createActions()
        self.makeConnections()
        self.listViewMethod()

    def createActions(self):
        self.UndoAct = QtWidgets.QAction("Undo", self)
        self.UndoAct.setShortcut(QtGui.QKeySequence.Undo)
        self.UndoAct.triggered.connect(self.undoStack.undo)
        self.RedoAct = QtWidgets.QAction("Redo", self)
        self.RedoAct.setShortcut(QtGui.QKeySequence.Redo)
        self.RedoAct.triggered.connect(self.undoStack.redo)
        self.toolbar = self.addToolBar('Exit')
        self.toolbar.addAction(self.UndoAct)
        self.toolbar.addAction(self.RedoAct)


    def listViewMethod(self):
        self.listView = QtWidgets.QListView()
        self.listView.setModel(self.model)
        self.listView.setWindowTitle('ListView')
        self.listView.show()

    def makeConnections(self):
        self.model.itemDataChanged.connect(self.itemDataChangedSlot)

    def setModel(self, model):
        self.mapper = QtWidgets.QDataWidgetMapper(self)
        self.mapper.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Vertical)
        self.mapper.setModel(self.model)
        self.mapper.addMapping(self.LineEdit1, 0)
        self.mapper.addMapping(self.LineEdit2, 1)
        self.mapper.addMapping(self.ComboBox1, 2)
        self.mapper.addMapping(self.ComboBox2, 3)
        self.mapper.addMapping(self.TableWidget.cellWidget(0,0), 4)
        self.mapper.addMapping(self.TableWidget.cellWidget(1,0), 5)
        self.mapper.addMapping(self.TableWidget.cellWidget(2,0), 6)
        self.mapper.addMapping(self.TableWidget.cellWidget(3,0), 7)
        self.mapper.addMapping(self.TableWidget.cellWidget(4,0), 8)
        self.mapper.toFirst()

    def itemDataChangedSlot(self, index, oldValue, value, role):
        if role == QtCore.Qt.EditRole:
            command = CommandTextEdit(self, index, oldValue, value, "Text changed from '{0}' to '{1}'".format(oldValue, value))
            self.undoStack.push(command)

def main():

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())



if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```